# How to call a function by its name, passed as parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, ecmascript-6

How to call a function by its name, passed as parameter? My use case is the next, I have a `switch case` where I set the `data` of an api ajax call, once that ajax is complete it should be call `print function` passing the data result as parameter. I'm not sure this is a good approach, is there any better and easier way to do what I'm trying? Maybe with `async`/`promises`?

```
function printUpcoming(data) {
    //stuff
}

function printRecently(data) {
    //stuff
}

function printPopular(data) {
    //stuff
}

function requestAjax(dataSend, callFunctionByName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api-url",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "user-key": "userkey"
        },
        data: dataSend,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            jsonVal = data[0];
            //Call the function print depending of switch case option
            callFunctionByName(jsonVal);
        }
    });
}

switch (param) {
    case "upcoming":
        dataSend = "fields * where whatever 1";
        functionName = printUpcoming();
        requestAjax(dataSend, functionName);
        break;
    case "recently":
        dataSend = "fields * where whatever 2";
        functionName = printRecently();
        requestAjax(dataSend, functionName);
        break;
    case "popular":
        dataSend = "fields * where whatever 3";
        functionName = printPopular();
        requestAjax(dataSend, functionName);
        break;
}
```

Comment: `functionName = printUpcoming();` this will *execute* `printUpcoming` and assign the result to `functionName`. You probably want `functionName = printUpcoming` - just the reference to the function. Related `callFunctionByName` and `functionName` are misleading - you aren't passing the name of the function but a reference to it.

Comment: the way you've written it makes no sense to have `dataSend` and `functionName` variables anyway ... did you want a single `requestAjax(dataSend, functionName);` after the switch instead?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thats it, I want to make one ajax request after the `switch case` and call a specific `function` depending on the `swicht case`

Comment: then do what the first comment suggests

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok thank you, and do you think is there any better or simpler way to do this, maybe Im overthinking this? Or I leave it just as it is? Regards.

Comment: guess it depends on how complex `// stuff` is :p

Comment: `//stuff`is basically loop the json data returned by the api and print a tag with these values. Each json returned by the ajax can have a different structure.

Comment: The easier way would be to just do `return $.ajax()` and instead of attaching a `success:` handler as an option, to just use the [jQuery Deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) that `.ajax` returns and attach a handler via [`.done`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) or something. Easier than passing the function to just call it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to group functions into an object:

```
const Printer = {
    upcoming(data) {...},
    recently(data) {...},
    popular(data) {...},
}
```

and then

```
requestAjax(dataSend, param)
```

and in `requestAjax`

```
Printer[funcName](jsonVal))
```

Another option, as @VLAZ suggested, is to get rid of callbacks completely:

```
async function requestAjax(dataSend) {...}

...

printUpcoming(await requestAjax(...))
```

Example:

```js
function printUpcoming(x) {
  console.log('Upcoming!', x)
}

async function request() {
  return $.ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
}

async function process(param) {
  switch (param) {
    case "upcoming":
      printUpcoming(await request());
      break;
    case "recently":
      printRecent(await request());
      break;
  }
}

process('upcoming')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The `funcName` inside printer would the the `param` passed in `requestAjax`? With the `async` could you make it a bit more detailed explanation and a example based on my code? Im very new with `async` functions. Regards.

Comment: Yes, `funcName` is what you call `callFunctionByName`. For `async` see e.g. https://petetasker.com/using-async-await-jquerys-ajax/

Comment: I took a look on mdn aync: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function But I still cannot figure the way to apply it to my code. If yould could point me to the right direction I would gladly accept your answer.

Comment: @SilverSurfer: added an example

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `fetch` over jQuery's `$.get`. To call a function by it's name, you could use `eval`, **but I do not recommend using eval!** It may lead to security risks and weird errors. Instead, you can create index of your functions like this:

```
const AJAX_HANDLERS = { printUpcoming, printRecently, printPopular };
```

Then using fetch:

```
async function requestAjax(dataSend, handlerFunction) {

    if (typeof handlerFunction == "string") {
        // Convert "name" to "printName"
        const fnName = "print" + (handlerFunction).replace(/^([a-z])/i, (x, m1) => x.toLocaleUpperCase());
        if (typeof AJAX_HANDLERS[fnName] == "function") {
            handlerFunction = AJAX_HANDLERS[fnName];
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("Invalid function callback name: " + fnName)
        }
    }

    const fetchSettings = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "user-key": "userkey"
      },
      body: dataSend
    };
    const result = await fetch("api-url", fetchSettings);
    const jsonResponse = await result.json();

    handlerFunction(jsonResponse[0]);
}
```